# Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher; (3)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Установил eclipse, jdk8, sdk и libGDX. С помощью gdx_setup.jar с генерировал проект под desktop и android. Когда пытаюсь запустить проект под android (класс AndroidLauncher) в эмуляторе, сразу после запуска, происходит краш программы .

---

Код класса-запускалки AndroidLauncher

```
package com.game.test;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.game.test.MainClassOfTestGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MainClassOfTestGame(), config);
    }
}
```

---

вывод LogCat

```
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher; (3)
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): Link of class 'Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher;' failed
03-12 05:08:46.056: D/AndroidRuntime(2413): Shutting down VM
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d7cb20)
03-12 05:08:46.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

---

везде советуют добавить Android Private Libraries в build path. Но эти библиотеки и так добавлены [вот скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iebhE.png)

---

если кто то что то знает, пожалуйста, отпишитесь(((

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, надо было поставить галочку еще и на Project and External Dependencies.
Хотя я делал это и раньше, но заработало только сейчас, когда я кидал туда-сюда библиотеки а потом их удалял.